# Reference Request Separation of variables for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I was wondering if anyone knew good references for exercises, examples, theory for Separation of Variables for various PDE. Shearer and Levy has a chapter on it (chapter 6) but there are only a few exercises) and Evans also has a small snippet of it in chapter 4, but also not very many exercises.

Comment: [Strauss](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Partial+Differential+Equations%3A+An+Introduction%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470054567) maybe?

Comment: At least half of the book by [Haberman](https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems-Mathematics/dp/0134995430/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3IXI0XJENPYWJ&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.p-jqoD69jnlamaZI9_p5uC-Z2Tqc9eaEiv8CPZgKMrGM1ct9aUTZfroz-ksOmWDputoBMy98YgLBlD7WaYcRdDwGoJ-5UMgNkyicyRdq3HU.T7aX5hroYrdMKJMfRBijkLThXvwWDMhCf6CY-g0Gwxk&dib_tag=se&keywords=haberman+pde&qid=1708378993&sprefix=haberman+%2Caps%2C614&sr=8-1) is devoted to the separation of variables.